# Function "setSeconds( )" does not work with p5.js web Editor

Tags: javascript, date, p5.js, seconds

As you would expect, setSeconds(); would usually return and set the current date's seconds passed to the specified value that is inside the parameters. But whatever I try in the p5.js web Editor, it has absolutely no effect.

I wanted to make some code that would calculate the angle (from the horizontal) and the direction of a moving object. Tried inserting the function everywhere imaginable in my code, and even isolated my snippet of code from the rest to make sure no unwanted exterior code (like other variables) were affecting it.

```
function seconds_Passed()
{  
  timePassed = new Date() 
  timePassed.setSeconds(0); //Has no effect even though many js examples show 
                            //this as the way to do it.
  secondsPassed = timePassed.getSeconds();
  console.log(secondsPassed);
}
```

There are no error messages. 
The expected results are: for the seconds to always begin at 0 when I run the code, not the actual live seconds passing that you see on your desktop clock.

Comment: sorry but didn't get what you mean. The setSeconds() method sets the seconds of a date object. and i tested it and it's working. what you want to achieve with this function? @David

Answer (score 1):

`setSeconds()` is not a p5.js function, this is a standard JS method that sets the seconds for a specified date according to local time [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setSeconds).

So parsing:-

```
function seconds_Passed()
{  
  timePassed = new Date() 
  timePassed.setSeconds(0); //Has no effect even though many js examples show 
                            //this as the way to do it.
  secondsPassed = timePassed.getSeconds();
  console.log(secondsPassed);
}
```

Will always return 0 for the seconds.

If you need to get the time between two events you will need to capture two timestamps.

eg:-

```js
function seconds_Passed()
{  
  const date = new Date();
  const start = date.getTime();
  console.log("Start UNIX time " + start);
  
  setInterval(() => {
   const nowDate = new Date();
   const timeParsed = (Math.round((nowDate.getTime() - start) / 1000));
    console.log(timeParsed + ' Seconds parsed since script started');
  }, 3000)
}

seconds_Passed()
```

Another example showing on a button click:-

```js
const date = new Date();
const start = date.getTime();

function buttonClicked()
{
   const nowDate = new Date();
   const timeParsed = (Math.round((nowDate.getTime() - start) / 1000));
    console.log(' It took you ' + timeParsed + ' second to click the button');
}
```

```html
<button onclick="buttonClicked()">
Click me
</button>
```

Comment: I appreciate it. But could you also expand on why the web editor does not contain the function? I stumbled across this editor randomly assuming it was basically Javascript? If not, then what is it? And why is it called "p5.js" then if it does not have some standard Javascript functions?

Comment: I have just tested your code in p5.js and it works exactly as expected. https://editor.p5js.org/henslersoftware/sketches/ZYsINHkkK